# I am having problems creating a proper android gridview layout

Tags: android, gridview, layout, scrollview

I am trying to create a simple gridview layout but I am not successful at all doing it. I have created the one below as you can see, but I want to be able to scroll the whole screen along with the "Test Header" and also be able to appear all the items and not cut them at the middle of the screen as you see from the photo below.

http://s23.postimg.org/sz7jca9m3/Screenshot_2014_06_18_17_21_57.png

The Layout I am using is the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/home_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test Header"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardGridView
                android:id="@+id/myGrid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:columnWidth="160dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                card:list_card_layout_resourceID="@layout/grid_gplay" >
            </it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardGridView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I would appreciate any ideas or help here.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

Remove

Your gridview will work properly..`<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/home_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >`